# Switching facingMode with applyConstraints not CURRENTLY supported (Media Stream Api)

Tags: javascript, constraints, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

I am reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints) and almost halfway through it, you can read about the following

```
function switchCameras(track, camera) {
  let constraints = track.getConstraints();
  constraints.facingMode = camera;
  track.applyConstraints(constraints);
}
```

> This function accepts a MediaStreamTrack and a string indicating the
>   camera facing mode to use, fetches the current constraints, sets the
>   value of the MediaTrackConstraints.facingMode to the specified value,
>   then applies the updated constraint set.

But when giving it a try on the live demo at the end of the article, I am trying to change the `facingMode` `videoConstraint` on a `MediaStreamTrack` initiated with `getUserMedia` while streaming using `track.applyConstraints(constraints);`

For example, if started with `getUserMedia()` on these constraints:

```
{
  video: {
    "facingMode": "user"
  },
  audio: false
}
```

and using `applyConstraints()` with this configuration:

```
{
    "facingMode": { "exact": "environment" }
}
```

the output is an error

- in Android (Chrome): `Error OverconstrainedError in contraint facingMode: Cannot satisfy constraints`
- in iOS (Safari): `Error OverconstrainedError in constraint facingMode: Constraint not supported`
  and I tried also with a friend on a Windows surface and they received a similar error.

References to these issues are found within [this article](https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/) and [this forum bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=179363).
So my question is, **is this an expected behavior or are the help on those two and the first article outdated?**

Additionally I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to correctly switch cameras using the `applyConstraints()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you found any solution for this issue? i am badly stuck on this issue man

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why the facingMode error is because it is a different device.

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch a MediaStream from a front to a back camera, or vice versa. To do that you need to open a new stream with getUserMedia.